# MvvmCross - How to get iOS Views to load from a different assembly?

Tags: cross-platform, mvvmcross, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get the Views in my xamarin-forms + mvvmcross project to load correctly with no luck.

Project structure breakdown:

> Project: Shared.Core - 100% cross platform code, view models, models,
> etc..
>
> Project: Shared.Mobile - Xamarin-forms views
>
> Project: iOS - uses shared views
>
> Project: Android - uses shared views
>
> Project: UWP - uses shared views
>
> Project: WPF - uses WPF native views

I have a working WPF project using mvvmcross and am trying to get the mobile going starting with iOS.

The iOS project is only loading the views when the views and viewmodels are in the same assembly. Otherwise I am getting:

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
> NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Application windows are
> expected to have a root view controller at the end of application
> launch

The same can be seen from this sample project by taking the PCL Views folder and moving it to the iOS project.

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Forms/tree/master/Samples/Example001XAML

I have also tried the following to no avail:

Setup.cs

```
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> GetViewModelAssemblies()
{
    var result = base.GetViewModelAssemblies();
    var assemblyList = result.ToList();
    assemblyList.Add(typeof(FirstViewModel).Assembly);
    return assemblyList.ToArray();
}

protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> GetViewAssemblies()
{
    var result = base.GetViewAssemblies();
    var assemblyList = result.ToList();
    assemblyList.Add(typeof(FirstPage).Assembly);
    return assemblyList.ToArray();
}
    
protected override void InitializeViewLookup()
{
    base.InitializeViewLookup();

    var vmLookup = new Dictionary<Type, Type> {
        {typeof (FirstViewModel), typeof (FirstPage)},
        {typeof (AboutViewModel), typeof (AboutPage)}
    };

    var container = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewsContainer>();
    container.AddAll(vmLookup);
}
```

Comment: Oh wait. I reread your post and now I am thinking. What is going on in your AppDelegate? It is complaining about no windows are presented at the end of app launch, meaning something is probably missing in there. AppDelegate.cs please.

Comment: From the Example001XAML project, Literally the only change done was to move the "Pages" folder containing the xaml pages down into the iOS project thus separating the views from the view models(the same way my actual project does). No changes were made to the AppDelegate.

Then Setup.cs was changed as posted to try and fix it.

Comment: After looking a bit more into the innards, I have found there is an issue here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Forms/blob/master/MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core/MvxFormsPageLoader.cs#L44 Problem is that it always looks in the same Assembly as the ViewModel and ignores the ViewLookup. Will look into fixing this soon and give you a workaround.

Comment: This is fixed in the viewlookup branch: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Forms/pull/46 You can either wait for me to push out new NuGet packages (probably sometime tomorrow) or you can check the branch out and build it yourself. I will edit my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just fixed this in the Forms presenter core so it now works! You were on the right track with overriding `GetViewsAssemblies` or `InitializeViewLookup`. That is how it should work if the presenter had been implemented correctly to begin with.

Anyways, with the new changes in this [Pull Request](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Forms/pull/46) the way it works is:

Either override `GetViewsAssemblies` to let `InitializeViewLookup` internally map Views to ViewModels, from the found views in where you tell MvvmCross to look for them. The code in `Setup.cs` will look something like:

```
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> GetViewAssemblies()
{
    var result = base.GetViewAssemblies();
    var assemblyList = result.ToList();
    assemblyList.Add(typeof(FirstPage).Assembly);
    return assemblyList;
}
```

Where `FirstPage` is one of the pages in an Assembly containing views.

Or you can explicitly tell MvvmCross how to map Views to ViewModels in InitializeViewLookup:

```
protected override void InitializeViewLookup()
{
    base.InitializeViewLookup();

    var vmLookup = new Dictionary<Type, Type> {
        {typeof (FirstViewModel), typeof (FirstPage)}
    };

    var container = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewsContainer>();
    container.AddAll(vmLookup);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking a look at this, but I tried your suggested (as shown in my edit above) and I still get the same error. Any further suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have any further ideas?

Comment: Make a repro sample put it on github and I'll give it a spin

Comment: These fixes are now pushed to NuGet. https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter/4.0.2