# mvvmcross loading views and view models from different assemblies

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am trying to use views and view models in from separate assemblies. I have read the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17200358/4550962 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35358504/4550962 and none of it is satisfying for me.

The methods GetViewAssemblies() and GetViewModelAssemblies() does not make any effect - the views are not loaded. The method InitializeViewLookup() work as expected, but it requires to pair all views and view models manually.

1. Steps that was taken to reproduce problem:
2. Download samples: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Forms.git
3. Run MvvmCross_Forms_Examples solution

**For 001XAML, Example.W81:**

1. Update mvvmcross to 4.2.3, Xamarin.Forms to 2.3.1.114
2. Create two new portable project libraries: Views, ViewModels
3. Add Silverlight targets for libraries
4. Move directories **Pages** and **ViewModels** to apriopriate portable libraries
5. Add necessary references.
6. Add code to Setup.cs:

   ```
   protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> GetViewAssemblies()
   {
       var list = new List<Assembly>();
       list.AddRange(base.GetViewAssemblies());
       list.Add(typeof(Example.Pages.FirstPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

       return list;
   }

   protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> GetViewModelAssemblies()
   {
       var list = new List<Assembly>();
       list.AddRange(base.GetViewModelAssemblies());
       list.Add(typeof(Example.ViewModels.FirstViewModel).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

       return list;
   }
   ```
7. Run - the effect is `ArgumentNullException`: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: newRoot

> at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.Platform.SetPage(Page newRoot)
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.WindowsBasePage.LoadApplication(Application
>   application)    at Example.W81.MainPage..ctor()    at
>   Example.W81.Example_W81_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_4_MainPage()    at
>   Example.W81.Example_W81_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()

8. Comment code from 6) and add:

   ```
   protected override void InitializeViewLookup()
   {
       var viewModelLookup = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
       {
           {typeof(ViewModels.AboutViewModel), typeof(Pages.AboutPage)},
           {typeof(ViewModels.FirstViewModel), typeof(Pages.FirstPage)}
       };

       var container = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewsContainer>();
       container.AddAll(viewModelLookup);
   }
   ```
9. Run - works like a charm

Comment: Could you please upload your modified solution?

Comment: Here it is: https://bitbucket.org/equo/mvvmcross_test.git